# why 'select (0 < 1)' does not work in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I let MySQL execute `SELECT (0 < 1)`, it return 1; But if I run this select statement with SQL Server, it give me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

I also have tested other operator like != and <, and get the same error. I'm confused. '0 < 1' is an expression, why can't SQL Server evaluate it?

Comment: use this one instead `select iif(0 < 1, 1, 0)`

Comment: Because SQL Server does not support boolean expressions like that (and MySQL neither btw, because it does not actually support boolean expressions either but merely treats anything that can be converted to `1` as true which is not the same as a boolean expression)

Comment: As Metals points out - it needs to be an evaluation in SQL Server, as MySQL and SQL Server does not always use the exact same logic and hereby coding evaluation to get the same result.

Comment: Seems like SQL Server doesn't support boolean expressions in the select list. Portable alternative is `case when 0 < 1 then 1 else 0 end`, will run on "all" dbms's.

Comment: @Atmira: The query shown is valid "in SQL" - just not in "SQL Server"

Comment: What's the point of this expression? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: using a boolean expression is quite common (in DBMS that support them). E.g. `select middle_name is not null as has_middlename` or `select some_value > threshold as too_high`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that doesn't explain why `0>1` is used. It could be a "clever" idea used to create catch-all queries. Something that would be easier or faster to do differently.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , I want to know what's the value of `len(null) < 1` and get an error when executing `select (len(null) < 1)`, so I simplify the expression and ask here.

Comment: `LEN(NULL)` is unknown aka NULL. Period.

Comment: For MS SQL Server interestingly that same expression is valid as a boolean in the where, but not in select list.

Comment: @AlpacaMan NULL isn't a value at all, so what's the point of using `LEN(NULL)` much less `len(null) < 1`? The result of the entire expression is NULL in MySQL too. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I'm a beginner of Sql Server and used to work with MySQL. Now I'm debugging a stored procedure in a Sql Server database, there is one line code in this stored procedure: `if len(@keyword) < 1` where  @keyword is not assigned after declared. So I guess it may be a bug. To confirm that, I need to know what's the value of `len(@keyword) < 1`.

Comment: `select cast(iif(len(@keyword)>0,1,0) as bit)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This behavior is by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type):

> Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be
>   specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot
>   be returned in a result set.
>
> [...]
>
> Expressions with Boolean data types are used in the WHERE clause to
>   filter the rows that qualify for the search conditions and in
>   control-of-flow language statements such as IF and WHILE

So Boolean datatype exists, you just cannot use it outside WHERE clause (etc).

---

The correct SQL Server equivalent of MySQL `SELECT x < 1` (which returns 0, 1 or NULL) would be:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN x < 1       THEN 1
           WHEN NOT (x < 1) THEN 0
           ELSE             NULL -- you can omit this line
       END
```

Finally, `LEN(NULL)` is NULL and (generally speaking) any operation on NULL yields NULL. So the condition `IF LEN(NULL) < 1` will not execute, neither will `IF LEN(NULL) >= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL doesn't have a boolean type. It supports boolean *expressions*, but those cannot be values in variables or result sets.

The best you can do is something like

```
select case when 0 < 1 then 0 else 1 end
```

The result set will have a normal integer (the `bit` type is sometimes used to represent true/false values, but it's just a number with possible values of 1 and 0).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused. '0 < 1' is an expression, why can't SQL Server evaluate it?

It sort of is and sort of isn't. It's a *predicate*, and SQL Server treats predicates differently from other expressions which produce *values*.

SQL Server doesn't have a user-visible boolean data type so you cannot write an expression that produces a value of this non-existent data type.

You can only use predicates in specific positions, such as the `WHERE` clause, `ON` clauses, `WHEN` clauses (part of a `CASE` expression) and `CHECK` constraints (there are others)

Comment: Well `0 < 1` **is** an expression as well.

Comment: And the <comparison predicate> is <predicate>, and the <predicate> is a <boolean primary>, and the <boolean primary> is a <boolean test>, and the <boolean test> is a <boolean factor>, and the <boolean factor> is a <boolean term>, and the <boolean term> is a <boolean value expression>.